# jquery row blink after insert and fade in

Tags: jquery

I'm inserting row into table. After insertion I would like row just to fade in. For that I'm using

```
myrow.hide();
myrow.fadeIn(2000);
```

Problem is that entire row blinks after I use fadeIn command. How can I dela with this? Thank you

I added some part of the code bellow

```
var myrow = $('#'+row_above);
var myrow_html = "";
myrow_html += "<tr>";
myrow_html += some more html...

myrow.after(myrow_html);
var newrow = myrow.next();
newrow.hide();
newrow.fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: and how are you exactly inserting the row?

Comment: hide the row before inserting and then use fadein myrow.fadeIn(2000);

Comment: I did that. I't blinks AFTER insert and fadeIn

Answer (score 0):

```
var myrow = $('#'+row_above);    
var myrow_html = $("<tr>");

myrow_html.html('some more html...');
myrow_html.css('display', 'none');
myrow .after(myrow_html);

myrow_html.fadeIn(2000);
```

What about this...

Comment: myrow_html is not html tag. It's just html code i put together to describe table row

Comment: i know that. in your code its not html tag. But I made it jquery object.